# Game dosen't start when test pushes start button

Tags: android, testing, junit, sendkeys

I'm developing a 2D arcade game and writing tests (in a seperate Android JUnit Test Project). I need game running for some test methods. I wrote the following code:

```
public void testGameStart() throws InterruptedException {
    _activity.runOnUiThread(
              new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    _gameView.requestFocus();
                } // end of run() method definition
              } // end of anonymous Runnable object instantiation
            ); // end of invocation of runOnUiThread
    //start game
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU,
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
    Sub.sleep(10000); //wait 10 seconds
```

While running this test, I see menu appears and "start" highlighted, but then I don't see game starts on the emulator. But, when I click "MENU" and then "start" by myself during test run, it starts. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is strange to me, but the following code works the way I needed:

```
this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

Thanks AeroDroid for trying to answer. Maybe my previous code exactly gets focus on button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this directly answers your question, but I'm going to base my answer on what I think you're trying to say; I apologize if I misunderstand it. I think the "highlighting" you're referring to is just the start button being focused. The start button of course will not be pressed or activated if you are simple focused on it. From the code you've provided, I wouldn't ever start an action by trying to literally force what a user would do. If you made the menu, don't you know how to start the game. Is there no way in your program to call what's in the start button?

Comment: If I inderstand you well, you suggested using direct access to menu through it's methods. I heard from two people, that tests must use public methods, they must be like users. So they must send key presses (or touches - but they don't work well in my case). SpinnerTest example follows the idea: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html